# Testing expo with enzyme: jest-environment-enzyme does not export getVmContext

Tags: jestjs, expo, enzyme

I'd like to use enzyme to test my React-Native components in Expo managed project.
I follow the docs for [jest-expo-enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expo-enzyme), but now I get:

```
Test environment found at "/Users/raarts/myproject/node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/lib/index.js" does not export a "getVmContext" method, which is mandatory from Jest 27. This method is a replacement for "runScript".
```

My guess from here is that `jest-environment-enzyme` (last release 2 years ago), somehow needs to be updated for jest 27, but given `jest-expo-enzyme` was released 2 months ago, I figured I must be doing something wrong. Clueless on how to proceed.

Anybody has any advice?

Answer (score 7):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme-matchers/issues/351) in enzyme. A workaround is provided in [this comment](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme-matchers/issues/351#issuecomment-976009553).

The solution is to force upgrade `jest-environment-jsdom` package.
The better way to do it is via resolutions, if you are using Yarn, add this to your package.json:

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "27.4.6"
  },
```

Check for the latest version of [jest-environment-jsdom](https://npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-jsdom) and change it if necessary.

You can also do this in classic NPM using the [npm-force-resolutions package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions).

**Note**: you may encounter other problems after fixing this one, if you get a `setImmediate` error see [this comment](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8558#issuecomment-1006100001)

Comment: I'm getting the original error with these packages:    
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jest-cli": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "^1.0.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.8.0",
    "jest-runtime": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.1",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.4.0",
    "@jest/core": "^27.5.1",
    "@jest/transform": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",

Any idea what the issue could be? I tried `yarn add -W jest@24.4.7` but it didn't work, maybe since jest/core was still new?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on Next js project and using Jest and enzyme for testing, and for me I was able to fix this error by changing
testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
to
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
in jest.config.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install next package:

```
npm i jest-environment-jsdom
```