# does not export a "getVmContext" method, which is mandatory from Jest 27. This method is a replacement for "runScript"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Test environment found at "D:\production_tasks\alphastreet-data-services\api\node_modules\jest-environment-node\build\index.js" does not export a "getVmContext" method, which is mandatory from Jest 27. This method is a replacement for "runScript"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that your problem and solution is the same as what's suggested in this answer as a workaround to the bug in jest-enzyme:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943283/396138